# React Native wait for async func

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await

I wanna add multiple photo to db by Array.map() and after that add Array with url storage to collection.

I have problem with async function, because i should wait for this function await addImages() but something is not good.

```
    const addImages = async () => {
    image.map(async (imagePhoto)  => {
        const childPath = `post/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;
        const response = await fetch(imagePhoto);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        const task = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref()
            .child(childPath)
            .put(blob);

        const taskProgress = snapshot => {
            console.log(`transferred: ${snapshot.bytesTransferred}`)
        }

        const taskCompleted = () => {
            task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) => {
                imageDB.push(snapshot)
            })
        }

        const taskError = snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot)
        }

        task.on("state_changed", taskProgress, taskError, taskCompleted);

    })
    
}
const addToDbServices = async () => {
    await addImages();

    firebase.firestore().collection("services")
    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .collection("userServices")
    .add({
        nameService,
        errorCode,
        description,
        imageDB,
        status,
        creation: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    }).then(() => {
        Alert.alert('Serwis', 'Twoje zgłoszenie zostało pomyślnie dodane'),
        navigation.goBack()
    })
}
```

Comment: You need to return Promise's from your `image.map` function. Then you'll get an array of Promises, which you can wait for, using `Promise.all`

Answer (score 1):

```
image.map(async (imagePhoto)  => {...})
```

This creates an array of promises. These are executed but not awaited by default, so code execution continues regardless whether the operations are finished or not. If you want to await all these promises you can use `Promis.all()` like that:

```
const addImages = async () => {
  const pendingOperations = image.map(async (imagePhoto)  => {...});
  // wait until all images are processed
  return Promise.all(pendingOperations); // or await Promise.all(pendingOperations);
}

const addToDbServices = async () => {
  await addImages();
  ...
}
```

Comment: I tried like you wrote but i got the same result.

Comment: you just said "something is not good". What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) => {
                    imageDB.push(snapshot)
                })` 
Here i pushed links to array "imageDB" after that i wanna add this array images link to db collection here 
`firebase.firestore().collection("services")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection("userServices")
        .add({
            nameService,
            errorCode,
            description,
            imageDB,
            status,
            creation: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        })`

Comment: but addImages() func and firestore running in the same time. In result i get empty imageDB array